# CCLabelBMFont on CCMenuItemFont

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to change the "classic" mark felt font whit my personal fnt font on the menu voices. This is my code,for example i want change the font for "resume" and "quit".

```
    CCLabelBMFont* label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Paused" fntFile:@"score.fnt"];

    label.position = ccp(240, 160);

    [self addChild: label];

    [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Marker Felt"];
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:35];


    CCMenuItem *Resume = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Resume"
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(resume:)];


    CCMenuItem *Quit = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"QUIT"
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(GoToMainMenu:)];
```

Ok, with CCLabelBMFont for the pause it works, for the other it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCLabelBMFont` expects a bitmap font, while `CCMenuItem` takes a *normal* font.

If you want to create a menu item from a bitmap font, you probably first have to create a `CCLabelBMFont` and wrap it into a `CCMenuItemLabel`

```
CCLabelBMFont* label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Resume" fntFile:@"score.fnt"];
CCMenuItemLabel* item = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label target:self selector:@selector(resume:)];
```

You might also try `CCMenuItemAtlasFont` which works with atlas fonts

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

```
[CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"yourFontName"];
```

before creating your menuitems with CCMenuItemFont.

Comment: Depends on what name do you try to set. Font name is not name of your fnt file. Open your fnt file with double-click. The name of the font will be displayed on the header of the window. And make sure that you added your font in application's info.plist

Comment: Prove? I have no possiblity to run any cocos2d project right now and actually I cannot understand, why should I prove something to you. I just looked through the documentation and suggest you to try this method. But you don't want to do anything by yourself.

Comment: I've tried with score, and score.fnt. I'm sure that the name is score.fnt, but it don't work. Thank you.